# Creating a sorted rank ID by two other columns

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to create a "timeID" column based on the another ID and the timestamp... I'm using data.table::setorder() and I'm most of the way there but timeID column is just populating with the timestamp value rather than a time ID (1,2,3,...n).  Image is my current output...

[image]

What am I missing here?

```
# Parse timestamp
df1[, Month := str_sub(df1$BaseTimeStamp, 4,6)]
df1[, Year := str_sub(df1$BaseTimeStamp, 8,11)]
df1[, Day := str_sub(df1$BaseTimeStamp, 1,2)]
df1[, Hour := str_sub(df1$BaseTimeStamp, 13,14)]
df1[, Min := str_sub(df1$BaseTimeStamp, 16,17)]
df1[, Sec := str_sub(df1$BaseTimeStamp, 19,20)]
df1[, timeParse := ymd_hms(paste(df1$Year,
                                 df1$Month,
                                 df1$Day,
                                 df1$Hour,
                                 df1$Min,
                                 df1$Sec))]
# Create timeStamp ID
df1[, timeID := setorder(df1, myID, timeParse), by = myID]
```

Desired outcome would be...
[image]

Comment: Not clear what values you're expecting here... `df1[order(timeParse), v := 1:.N, by=myID]`? Btw, str_sub is not the "right" way to extract those things. If you look at lubridate or data.table, there are functions like `?hour`, `?month`, etc

Comment: I edited to add a bare-bones example of my desired outcome.

Comment: Ok. If your data is sorted by timeParse, then `DT[, v := rowid(myID)]` should work.